# How to fix Operations must have unique identifier Semantic Error in Swagger Editor

Tags: swagger, springfox, swagger-editor

I'm getting below error in the swagger editor when I try to import YAML file in the swagger editor.

**Operations must have unique operationIds.**

I have the controller where I have defined like

```
method = { RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.POST }
```

So because of this 2 operation ID's are created with same name and getting this error. How can I fix this ? Apart from creating different controller methods for PUT and POST.

Comment: Does this answer your question -- [How to customize the value of operationId generated by Springfox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38821763/113116)

Comment: No. This link is to change the name of the OperationId that will be generated but my  RequestMapping has both the methods for the same function name. @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.POST })