# openapi codegen-maven-plugin eliminate suffix UsingGET in generated methods

Tags: spring-boot, code-generation, openapi-generator

I'm trying to generate interfaces from yaml file with openapi codegen-maven-plugin every thing is good except the generated methods having the suffix UsingGET as you can see in this exemple bellow :

```
  ResponseEntity<ApicatControl> retrieveRepeatedProductOfferingUsingGET(
    @Parameter(name = "category.id", description = "category.id", schema = @Schema(description = "")) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "category.id", required = false) String categoryId,
    @Parameter(name = "type", description = "type", schema = @Schema(description = "")) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "type", required = false) String type
);
```

And this is my configuration  for codegen-maven-plugin within pom.xml.

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>openapi-codegen-java-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>

                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/swagger/swagger.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                        <modelPackage>com.groupe.apicat.gu.api.resources.model</modelPackage>
                        <apiPackage>com.groupe.apicat.gu.api</apiPackage>
                        <output>${generated-sources-path}</output>
                        <templateDirectory>src/templates/service</templateDirectory>
                        <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                        <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                        <configOptions>
                            <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
                            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                            <sourceFolder>generated-sources</sourceFolder>
                            <dateLibrary>legacy</dateLibrary>
                            <returnResponse>true</returnResponse>
                            <library>spring-boot</library>
                            <useTags>true</useTags>
                            <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                            <useSwaggerAnnotations>true</useSwaggerAnnotations>
                            <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                            <delegatePattern>false</delegatePattern>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Please do you have any solutions!! thanks

Answer (score 1):

The method name "retrieveRepeatedProductOfferingUsingGET" is created within your swagger.yaml. There should be a parameter called "operationId" where you specify this name. So just change it there and build the project again.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using spring-fox to generate the spec as they an `OperationBuilderPlugin` configured automatically to suffix using that convention.

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38828012/4292841) from one of the maintainers to see how you can customize it yourself